# Name and language of symbol in astronomy book

Tags: the-sun, fundamental-astronomy, notation

I've been working on a programming project involving Peter Duffett-Smith's *Practical Astronomy With Your Calculator (3rd Ed.)*, which has a large number of mathematical/astronomical formulas in it. There's a part at the end of the book for symbols and abbreviations, which contains this:

[image]

After doing some Google-fu, I was unable to find the name of the symbol. Would anyone smarter than me (which should be quite a few of you... heck, quite a *lot*) know what this is? Hopefully there's Unicode for it...

Comment: Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) was able to identify it for me pretty quickly.  Might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a variant of pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(letter)#Variant_pi), or "pomega".

In LaTeX, you can get it by using

```
                                          \varpi
```

$$\varpi$$

[TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216358/using-mathematical-symbols-alpha-beta-implies-in-latex/216362#216362) has a question on the 'var' prefix, and [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#List_of_Mathematical_Symbols) has something relevant.

> The various forms of pi are present in Unicode as:
>
> - U+03A0 Π greek capital letter pi (HTML Π · Π)
> - U+03C0 π greek small letter pi (HTML π · π)
> - U+03D6 ϖ greek pi symbol (HTML ϖ · ϖ)
> - U+220F ∏ n-ary product (HTML ∏ · ∏)
> - U+1D28 ᴨ greek letter small capital pi (HTML ᴨ)
> - U+1D70B  mathematical italic small pi (HTML )
> - U+1D6D1  mathematical bold small pi (HTML ).

It is used to denote the [longitude of the periapsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_periapsis), as in your case.